# Having multiple cases in a select

Tags: mysql, sql-server, select, case, temporary

I have a problem in where I have to convert the following MSSQL to MySQL. I have two main issues.

1. "#WU" is a temporary table that doesn't work. I try to replace it with
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE WU but it errors out without an explanation.
2. I want to know is the correct way to call the multiple cases.

I've tried removing the MAX, and switching changing them to WU1 = (CASE WHEN rk = 1 THEN WU END), but that doesn't work.

The code is as follows:

```
SELECT ReqN,
MAX(CASE WHEN rk = 1 THEN WU END) AS WU1,
MAX(CASE WHEN rk = 2 THEN WU END) AS WU2,
MAX(CASE WHEN rk = 3 THEN WU END) AS WU3,
MAX(CASE WHEN rk = 4 THEN WU END) AS WU4,
MAX(CASE WHEN rk = 5 THEN WU END) AS WU5,
MAX(CASE WHEN rk = 6 THEN WU END) AS WU6,
MAX(CASE WHEN rk = 7 THEN WU END) AS WU7,
MAX(CASE WHEN rk = 8 THEN WU END) AS WU8

into #tblWU

FROM (SELECT ReqN, WUnit,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM tblDevWU AS B
    WHERE B.ReqN = A.ReqN
    AND B.WUnit <= A.WUnit) AS rk
    FROM tblDevWU AS A) as A 
    GROUP BY ReqN;
```

Comment: how you select two fields(`ReqN, WUnit`) from one-columned dataset(`COUNT(*)`)? Is this works at all?

Comment: The coding works in MSSQL, yes. They are selected from tblDevWU

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'm just lost in your brackets XD

Comment: Yeah. This wasn't programmed by me. I have the task of switching to MySQL. The original programmer is no longer working on the project. And he left no comments.

Comment: You can replace `CASE` rows  to `IF(rk=1, WU, NULL) WU1`

Comment: Is my undestanding that in mysql you should use IF(Cond, true, False) instead of CASE WHEN. Is this your complete code? of just a piece of it?

Comment: Its possible to use cases. I'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql equivalent for this is:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tblWU AS
SELECT ReqN,
MAX(IF(rk=1, WU, NULL)) WU1,
MAX(IF(rk=2, WU, NULL)) WU2,
MAX(IF(rk=3, WU, NULL)) WU3,
MAX(IF(rk=4, WU, NULL)) WU4,
MAX(IF(rk=5, WU, NULL)) WU5,
MAX(IF(rk=6, WU, NULL)) WU6,
MAX(IF(rk=7, WU, NULL)) WU7,
MAX(IF(rk=8, WU, NULL)) WU8
FROM (
   SELECT ReqN, WUnit,
      (
       SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblDevWU AS B
       WHERE B.ReqN = A.ReqN AND B.WUnit <= A.WUnit
      ) AS rk
   FROM tblDevWU AS A) as A 
GROUP BY ReqN;
```

Comment: Tried this one, It just errors out. Programming in PHPMyadmin doesn't give me a specific reason.

Comment: may be it's just very heavy query, and you can't to wait it's end? :)

Comment: I, myself, tried a similar method, but didn't use the AS after creating the temp table. Also without the if statement. Nice.